# How to filter log events and crashes in Firebase Crashlytics Console for user id?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

How can I filter user log events and crashes in Firebase Console assuming i know user id [set with](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android) `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId("12345");`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would just type in the User ID into the User ID searchbar in your dashboard. Here's a picture:

[image]